# getFilesDir() android function is undefined if i dont extend my class with activity

Tags: android

If i have my class as

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

//Extends Activity

public class MyClass extends Activity
{

File fileDir = getFilesDir(); //no error

   . ....    
}
```

But if i don't extend MyClass , i get an error saying "getFilesDir()" undefined.

some thing like

```
   public class MyClass2
    {

    ....

    File fileDir = getFilesDir(); //error

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the method of the [Context](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) class. You have to obtain an instance of the class to invoke it.

Comment: is there a way to get the internal files location without the Activity context?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir()

getFilesDir is member of ContextWrapper. So if you don't extend ContextWrapper it's normal for the compiler to throw error undefined reference.